# Unable to fetch Application Overview Page of a Running Application

Tags: apache-apex

Most of the times, I can't go to Application Overview of my application's Application Monitor Page. Sometimes when I go, all the stats on the page such as: Logical Plan, Physical Plan tabs don't exist at all and none of the stats show up. 
However, I don't have issues to go to Application Overview after the application is killed.

Here is the stacktrace on dtgateway.log whenever I can't go to Application Overiview Page:

```
2016-08-18 20:17:23,908 WARN com.datatorrent.stram.client.StramAgent: Caught exception when retrieving web service info for app application_1471123625804_0161
org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 500 No WebApplication provider is present</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /ws. Reason:
<pre>    No WebApplication provider is present</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: No WebApplication provider is present
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.WebApplicationFactory.createWebApplication(WebApplicationFactory.java:69)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.create(ServletContainer.java:391)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.create(ServletContainer.java:306)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:607)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:710)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.init(FilterDefinition.java:114)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.initPipeline(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:98)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:114)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter.doFilter(StaticUserWebFilter.java:109)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2$QuotingInputFilter.doFilter(HttpServer2.java:1296)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:767)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it might be a multiple/wrong jar file issue as discussed, for example, in:

[Jersey: No WebApplication provider is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17286865/jersey-no-webapplication-provider-is-present)

[Jersey No WebApplication provider is present when jersey-json dependency added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662919/jersey-no-webapplication-provider-is-present-when-jersey-json-dependency-added)